# angular-dimple error TypeError: Cannot read property '_hasCategories' of null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dimple.js

I am trying to build stacked-bar chart using [dimple.js](http://dimplejs.org) I need to do this through angular directives so I am using [angular-dimple](http://esripdx.github.io/angular-dimple/)

here is what I have coded to run their sample example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("dimpleTestApp", ['angular-dimple']);


        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService) {
        dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
        $scope.graphData = response.data;
        console.log($scope.graphData);
            });
        }])
        .service('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {
          return {
            getData: function() {
              return $http.get('data.json');
            }
          };
        }]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app='dimpleTestApp'>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <graph data="graphData" orientation="horizontal">
        <x-axis field="Month"></x-axis>
        <y-axis field="Sales"></y-axis>
        <stacked-bar field="storeId" value="2"></stacked-bar>
    </graph>

    </div>

</body>
```

but I am getting this error while running this code:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '_hasCategories' of null
at null.<anonymous> (http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js:1:10314)
at Array.forEach (native)
at _getSeriesData (http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js:1:9714)
at draw (http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js:1:20275)
at draw (http://localhost/angular-dimple/bower_components/angular-dimple/lib/angular-dimple.js:175:15)
at addBar (http://localhost/angular-dimple/bower_components/angular-dimple/lib/angular-dimple.js:428:25)
at Object.fn (http://localhost/angular-dimple/bower_components/angular-dimple/lib/angular-dimple.js:433:11)
at g.$get.g.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:110:464)
at g.$get.g.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:113:468)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:73:183)
```

can anybody tell me what is wrong with this application and how can I make this running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this by doing getting deeper into angular-dimple library.

There was mistake in their documentation directive is created using `x` and `y` elements while in example they have mentioned `x-axis` and `y-axis`, so when I changed it to correct one it worked.

Here is the modified code:

```
<graph data="graphData" orientation="horizontal">
        <x field="Month"></x>
        <y field="Sales"></y>
        <stacked-bar field="storeId" ></stacked-bar>
    </graph>
```